# How do I compare Integer and Long types with Junit?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

How do I compare Integer and Long types with Junit ?

The result of `assertThat(poiList.get(0).get("id_pk")).isEqualTo(member.getId_pk());` is:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
expected: 1L
but was : 1
Expected :1L
Actual :1
```

The two types are:

```
log.info("getClass1: {}", poiList.get(0).get("id_pk").getClass());
         log.info("getClass2: {}", member.getId_pk().getClass());
```

```
2021-09-30 15:29:08.904 INFO 19504 --- [ main] c.p.i.domain.item.ItemServiceTest : getClass1: class java.lang.Integer
2021-09-30 15:29:08.904 INFO 19504 --- [ main] c.p.i.domain.item.ItemServiceTest : getClass2: class java.lang.Long
```

How can I compare 1 and 1L to be equal?

best regards

Comment: You could cast the Integer to Long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert Integer to Long via `java.lang.Integer#longValue`:

```
assertThat(poiList.get(0).get("id_pk").longValue()).isEqualTo(member.getId_pk());
```

BUT beware of Null pointers, if `poiList.get(0).get("id_pk")` is null then a Null Pointer Exception will be thrown!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it should be corrected at entity level because if we say `poiList.get(0).get("id_pk")` is equal to `member.getId_pk()` then logically datatype for them should also be same.

As the preferred solution you should correct it entity level.

But if you still want to assert it then convert `int` to `long` first and then assert on that.

```
poiList.get(0).get("id_pk").longValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Java's Long class has an [.intValue() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) returning an int.
2. Java's Integer class has a [.longvalue() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

I would recommend the second, as long can take a larger range of values than int.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
assertThat(new BigDecimal(1)).isEqualTo(new BigDecimal(1L));
```

Answer (score 1):

As all answers show, you need to change one param's type. Maybe both change them to String is also a good idea.

```
 assertThat(String.valueOf(1L)).isEqualTo(String.valueOf(1))
```